# Debugging a SQL error in a SQL script line by line in DBeaver

Tags: sql, sqlite, debugging, foreign-keys, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver 23.1.2. The following SQL script is failing with the following SQL error:

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "type_id": syntax error)

Is there a way to debug the following SQL script in DBeaver line by line to see

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_types 
(
    type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    type_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY type_id REFERENCES my_types(type_id),
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created the table without the FOREIGN KEY, then I created the FOREIGN KEY manually via the DBeaver GUI, and this is what it now looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_types (
  type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  type_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id INTEGER,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT objects_FK FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES my_types(type_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

It seems the `CONSTRAINT` line must be at the end (or I guess at least after the 'local' `type_id` field is created which I think becomes the store for the FOREIGN KEY).